Why encoding change api does not work in php?
I need to save a UTF-8 text in a file with PHP using this code:
<?php

$filename = "";
if ($handle = opendir("test")) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        
        $filename = $file;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$arr = array(
    "name" => "اصغر",
    "family"=> "فرهادی",
    "Movies" => [
        "City" => "[جدایی نادر از سیمین]",
        "detail" => [
            "yearOf" => "2011",
            "language" => "persian"
        ]
    ]
);


$json =  json_encode($arr);
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($json);
echo $encoding."\n";

$json1 = mb_convert_encoding($json, "UTF-8");

$encoding2 = mb_detect_encoding($json1);

echo $encoding2."\n";

$h = fopen("out.txt","a+");
fwrite($h, $json1."\n");
fclose($h);

I run this code in the console using this command:

php index.php

and output is:

ASCII ASCII

and the content of the output file is:

{"name":"\u0627\u0635\u063a\u0631","family":"\u0641\u0631\u0647\u0627\u062f\u06cc","Movies":{"City":"[\u062c\u062f\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u062f\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u0646]","detail":{"yearOf":"2011","language":"persian"}}}

but I need to save the result in the file in Persian transcript. I also checked the iconv function, but the result was the same.

Think of encoding like currencies. You cannot just convert to US Dollar, you need to know the source currency, and you can't generally auto-detect currency if all you have is 29.95.

Once you've run json_encode, anything that wasn't ASCII has been escaped, as you can see in your output - \u0627 is just a series of ASCII characters. But it's not really clear what you're expecting mb_convert_encoding to do - what encoding do you think the text is currently in?

In this case, your text is hard-coded in your program's source code, so the encoding is decided by your text editor or IDE. In 2024, it's likely to be UTF-8 already.

As far as I can see, the JSON output you have shows that the text is indeed encoded as UTF-8 already: https://3v4l.org/hc82lG So I'm not sure what actual problem you're trying to solve.

This has nothing much to do with UTF-8. Throw out all the mb_convert_encoding calls and such and just add JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to json_encode. See the duplicate above. mb_detect_encoding detects ASCII because what json_encode returns is pure ASCII. It's also valid UTF-8 and valid in any number of other encodings. Which one it picks is sort of random for all intents and purposes.

@ÁlvaroGonzález That currency analogy is great, I'll try to remember that one.
